# Can I end a quote/dialogue with a colon?

Tags: punctuation, writing, colons, dialogue

If a character is introducing something, say, a PowerPoint presentation, how should I punctuate their speech? Can I use a colon?

For example:

"We have proof. Just take a look at this:" He swivelled in his chair and pointed to the screen which now showed a graph of the skyrocketing gas prices.

The colon doesn't look right to me, but neither does a comma (since the dialogue is succeeded by an action beat) or a full stop (it feels too final).

Similarly, if a character is reading something aloud, and I am including the complete article text, would you end the preceding dialogue with a colon? Here, a full stop seems even more wrong since the character is actually continuing to speak.

Example:

John cleared his throat. "I found this online. Listen to this:"

*SOARING GAS PRICES CAUSE MOTHER OF FOUR TO LOSE HOME*

*[rest of article text]*

Alternatively, should I include the whole article text in the quote to show that it is being read by John?

Comment: "Just take a look at this" would seem to require an exclamation mark, e.g., "We have proof. Just take a look at this!"

Comment: @KillingTime, You're right - that could work in this example. But it wouldn't always be the case, for example if the character said, "We have some photos here:" and then proceeds to show the pictures (on a screen or in print or whatever).

Comment: I would definitely use a full stop rather than a colon, if the next sentence is a description of the speaker's next action rather than a simple 'he said'.

Comment: Colons get a lot of licence, but the thing they introduce can't be postponed.

Comment: "Take a look at this..." or "Take a look at this!" depending on whether the speaker ended dramatically or just tailed off and let the image finish his sentence.